# Why doesn't powershell form close when calling function after close

Tags: powershell

I have a button on a form with the following code:

```
$BrowseButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$BrowseButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(97,75)
$BrowseButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$BrowseButton.Text = "Browse"
$BrowseButton.Add_Click({$pathForm.Close();getPath})
$pathForm.Controls.Add($BrowseButton)
```

My goal is for the $pathForm to close and the following function to be called:

```
Function getPath {

$app = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, "C:\")
if ($folder.Self.Path -ne "") {$selected = "You selected " + $folder.Self.Path}

}
```

Without the call to $getPath, the form will close as intended. However, when I add "getPath" to the click, the form doesn't close and the BrowseForFolder shell app opens behind it. What is causing it to stay open?

I am new to powershell and coding in general, so there may be an obvious error in my code. Thanks!

Comment: As a simple solution I removed the topmost attribute from my function and just let that window chill in the background until the getPath function is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the trouble is coming from the fact that the code run in the `Add_Click` function is executed by a message pump the same one that will execute the message to close the form. One solution would be to execute getPath in a `Start-job` CmdLet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ended up doing something else, but that would have worked as well.